# Space of almost complex structures on a compact manifold

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry, almost-complex

According to the book by  Huybrechts, *Complex Geometry: An Introduction*, this is a nice space and may be regarded, after some form of completion, as an infinite-dimensional manifold. How is this done, i.e. how is this space constructed as a manifold? I'd like some references.

I know how to construct the space of almost complex structures on a real even-dimensional vector space and show that it is a complex manifold. I would prefer a construction that departs from this point.